# Last then function being called multiple times

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to write a chain of Promises but the last *.then()* is being called multiple times and I don't know why. The last *.then()* must run a single time because it will call another API passing *result* as body.

I know that is being called multiple times because I'm logging as console.log().

What is wrong on my code? For my understand, then() should wait promise returns something.

```
app.post('/router/join', function(req, res){
    let data = req.body;
    sessions.validate(data)
    .then(result => {
        return {
            authenticated: (result.code === 201)                
        };
    })
    .then(result => {        
        if(result.authenticated){
            return contacts.getContacts(data.tenant_id).then(cs => {
                let json = merge(result, cs.data);            
                return Promise.all(cs.data.items.map(contact => {
                    return messages.getLastMessage(data.tenant_id, contact.item.contact_id, data.hash_id)
                        .then(result => {
                            contact.item.last_message = result.code === 200 && result.data.length > 0 ? result.data[0] : null;
                            return contact;
                        });                    
                })).then(result => {
                    json.items = result;
                    return json;
                });            
            });
        } else {
            return result;
        }        
    })
    .then(result => {
        //this call should run after all other promises and only a single time
        let event = result.authenticated ? 'valid_session' : 'invalid_session';
        console.log('222');
        proxy.send(event, result)}
    )
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('333');
        proxy.send('invalid_session', {socket_id: data.socket_id})
    })
    res.status(201).send({});
});
```

Comment: The code is so confusing!! Can't you implement these nested promises in other way?!

Comment: I’m new to promises, not sure how avoid nested promises

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await to clean it up.  Inside async functions you can await the results of promises.

```
app.post('/router/join', async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        let data = req.body;
        let {code} = await sessions.validate(data);
        let result = { authenticated: (code === 201) };     
        if (result.authenticated) {
            let cs = await contacts.getContacts(data.tenant_id);
            let json = merge(result, cs.data);            
            let items = Promise.all(cs.data.items.map(async contact => {
                let result = await messages.getLastMessage(data.tenant_id, contact.item.contact_id, data.hash_id)
                contact.item.last_message = result.code === 200 && result.data.length > 0 ? result.data[0] : null;
                return contact;
            }));   
            json.items = items;
            result = json;
        }
        let event = result.authenticated ? 'valid_session' : 'invalid_session';
        console.log('222');
        proxy.send(event, result);
        res.status(201).send({});
    } catch (err) {
        proxy.send('invalid_session', {socket_id: data.socket_id})
        next (err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using Node 6.10. Can't handle async/await :(

Comment: You can use https://babeljs.io to transpile async/await code into code node 6 can handle